# Spark converts 0 to null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra and one column in this table have a type Double, with value 0.

When I try to read this data using spark:

```
val dataFromCassandra = sqlContext.read
  .cassandraFormat("table_name", SomeKeyspace)
  .load()
```

it returns `null` value instead 0.

please help!!!

Comment: using spark 1.6

Comment: can you show the type of that column in the dataframe (the result of `dataFromCassandra.printSchema()`)?

Comment: type is double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with the Cassandra data source, but you can replace all `null`s of a certain column with some constant value (e.g. `0`) using `coalesce`:

```
df.show()
// +---+-----+
// | id|value|
// +---+-----+
// |  1| null|
// |  2| null|
// +---+-----+

df.withColumn("value", coalesce($"value", lit(0.0))).show() 
// +---+-----+
// | id|value|
// +---+-----+
// |  1|  0.0|
// |  2|  0.0|
// +---+-----+
```

Comment: it helped,tnx you